# Fix crackling audio with Pidgin Internet Messenger

Tags: 10.10, sound, pidgin

I've recently switched from Empathy to Pidgin as my IM client, but I've noticed the notification sounds Pidgin plays on events like a contact signing in crackle. I've never had such problems with any other sound on Ubuntu, but Pidgin seems to have a problem with my audio setup.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem until I opened Pidgin's sound properties and switch "method" from "auto" to "ALSA". Now it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has fixed my audio issues with pidgin! +1

Comment: confirm: fixed.